# Blog Title is using default link color

Tags: java, html, css, web, blogger

I have developed my site using a theme (HTML, CSS, JavaScript).
But the Blog Title is using default link color.

I have tried many ways to use the Title color, but I became unsuccessful to do that.

**How can I change the Title color?**

Title color is disabled
[image: Title color is disabled]

Title is using Default link color
[image: Title is using Default link color]

Comment: `.header-logo h1 a {color: #000}` use parent class to change link color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the css properties using `!important`.
So, the following change might help:

```
.header-logo h1 {
    color: #065445 !important;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply color property to "a" tag, not on h1. You can either use the following ways:

1. inline-CSS to impose this color to the title.
2. Use !important with color property of CSS.

   .header-logo h1 a{
   color: #065445 !important;
   }